# Python bitcoin miner not letting me define variable after mine

Tags: python-3.x

I have been trying to create a python bitcoin miner, that ACTUALLY puts the coins somewhere, so thats the first part of my quesiton, and the second part is how do I fix this error?

This is all of my code:

```
import hashlib
import time

max_nonce = 2 ** 32 # 4 billion

def proof_of_work(header, difficulty_bits):

    # calculate the difficulty target
    target = 2 ** (256-difficulty_bits)

    for nonce in range(max_nonce):
        hash_result = hashlib.sha256(str(header)+str(nonce)).hexdigest()

        # check if this is a valid result, below the target
        if int(hash_result, 16) < target:
            print ("Success with nonce %d" % nonce)
            print ("Hash is %s" % hash_result)
            return (hash_result,nonce)

    print ("Failed after %d (max_nonce) tries" % nonce)
    return nonce


if __name__ == '__main__':

    nonce = 0
    hash_result = ''

    # difficulty from 0 to 31 bits
    for difficulty_bits in range(32):

        difficulty = 2 ** difficulty_bits
        print ("Difficulty: %ld (%d bits)" % (difficulty, difficulty_bits))

        print ("Starting search...")

        # checkpoint the current time
        start_time = time.time()

        # make a new block which includes the hash from the previous block
        # we fake a block of transactions - just a string
        new_block = 'test block with transactions' + hash_result

        # find a valid nonce for the new block
        (hash_result, nonce) = proof_of_work((new_block, difficulty_bits).hexdigest()

        # checkpoint how long it took to find a result
        end_time = time.time()
```

The line above this, The end_time seems to get an error, with no definition to what the error is. Please help.

Please note that I have tried a great deal of commenting out a bunch of things, changing code, and this is in python 3

Comment: Can you see that the `proof_of_work` line is missing a closed parenthesis?  Or, more specifically, has two open parens where you only want one.  You have `proof_of_work((` instead of `proof_of_work(`.

Comment: I've done that, but now I get this:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 46, in <module>
    (hash_result, nonce) = proof_of_work(new_block, difficulty_bits).hexdigest()
  File "main.py", line 13, in proof_of_work
    hash_result = hashlib.sha256(str(header)+str(nonce)).hexdigest()
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this as an answer because of the many issues.

First, `hashllib` requires byte strings.  You would need

```
    hash_result = hashlib.sha256((header+str(nonce)).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
```

Second, you're doing `proof_of_work(...).hexdigest()`, but that function isn't returning a hash object.  You are already calling `hexdigest`.  Your function either returns a 2-tuple, or a `nonce`.  You want to remove the hexdigest call:

```
        # find a valid nonce for the new block
        (hash_result, nonce) = proof_of_work((new_block, difficulty_bits)
```

And, in the final line of `proof_of_work` change

```
    return nonce
```

to

```
    return (None, nonce)
```

Next, you are converting the nonce to decimal digits to tack it on to the block.  That is completely wrong.  The nonce needs to be a 4-byte value.  Something like:

```
    enonce = struct.pack('I', nonce)
    hash_result = hashlib.sha256(header.encode('utf-8')+enonce).hexdigest()
```

Finally, this whole thing is silly.  Have you timed that inner loop to see how long it takes?  On my box, it takes about 500 microseconds per loop.  To run that 4 billion times would require a month and a half.  To repeat that for all 32 difficult values would make it take 4 years.